# How to show the full text in mod_article_category?

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, mod-articles-category

I override the Joomla `mod_article_category`. I set hide introtext in Joomla CMS. And I used the `print_r($list)` to check the fulltext variable. However, there are [fulltext] but no content after `print_r($list)`. How can I display the fulltext in the `mod_article_category`?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the "Read more" separator in article's content editor, all the  text is actually stored in the *introtext* field.

Use that field to print full content or add the "read more" in your articles.